# Getting information for selected user problem when there are more then 1 user with the same name Java

Tags: java

I have got a data base which has senders and receiver one-to-many.

The problem that I am facing is when lets say I have 2 user same name "John smiths" with id 01 and "John Smiths" with id 2

I have a java application which reads all senders in a combo box but how do I relate that senders with there own set of receivers. How can I differentiate between the two "John Smiths"?

if I say `SELECT senderID FROM senderTable WHERE fullName="John Smiths"` it will return 2 ids.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some unique identifier(s) in the combo box too, otherwise your users won't be able to distinguish them either. The sender id is perfect for internal use, but not very user friendly - do you have some more identifiable data such as date of birth, mother's name, social security ID...?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a workaround to prevent this kind of scenario, but to resolve your case immediately, you could keep track of ComboBox Index mapping to a database id and then perform the search based on this id and not name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need additional information to distinguish between multiple people with the same name (such as their email address) and use that information in the select query to make sure you only get one result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Swing maybe you need a complex component in order to show relation between sender and receiver. Take a look at http://www.jidesoft.com/